# Как подключить сенсор к Raspberry Pi 4 B на неосновной spi

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

Raspberry Pi 4 B. Сенсорный экран 10.1 inch HDMI LCD with XPT2046 Touch Controller. ОС Simply Linux 10.2. На spi0 сенсор работает, на spi1 не работает. Я хочу подключить к второму spi потому что требуется два таких экрана и подключение ко второму spi это шаг на пути к этому. Подключение на spi1: SCLK GPIO 21, MOSI GPIO 20, MISO GPIO 19, CE1 GPIO 27 (пробовал так же на GPIO 17), P6 GPIO 18. Конфигурация /boot/efi/config.txt:

```
dtparam=spi=on
dtoverlay=spi0-2cs
dtoverlay=spi1-3cs
```

После правки конфига появились: /dev/spidev1.0, /dev/spidev1.1 и /dev/spidev1.2.

Подскажите ещё, что за контакт такой P6? В одном месте я находил, что что это reset, в другом, что CE0 и в третьем, что это пин прерывания сенсорной панели, где низкий уровень, пока сенсорная панель обнаруживает прикосновение.

Пробовал всё то же самое повторить на Raspbian, там вообще ничего не заработало, хотя появились так же /dev/spidev0.0 и /dev/spidev0.1.

Comment: А почему не оставить его на основном?

Comment: @eri в конечном итоге мне нужно два сенсорных экрана и это шаг на путик этому. Дополнил так же свой вопрос в связи с этим.

Comment: Теоретически SPI позволяет работать нескольким устройствам на одном SPI интерфейсе: общие линии MOSI, MISO, SCLK, отдельный только CS (chip select), выбор устройства выполняется установкой 0 в его CS. Но как там на Raspberry Pi не знаю. Под spi1 подразумевается отдельный cs или вообще отдельный интерфейс?

Comment: @insolor вот тут можно посмотреть распиновку Raspberry https://pinout.xyz/pinout/spi

Comment: Cs и int отдельно, остальное можно вместе.

Comment: @insolor spi 1 это в первую очередь отдельный тактовый генератор с отдельным каналом dma. Отдельный интерфейс  и свои линии данных.

Comment: Вон на spi0 два чипа можно вешать без костылей : ce0 и ce1

Comment: Ну в принципе понятно, можно попробовать оба экрана на один spi вешать

Comment: @eri Я попробовал переместить провод с GPIO 7 (CE1) на GPIO 8 (CE0). Так не заработало. Если я неправильно  понял, подскажите, пожалуйста, какой провод куда. Или может надо ещё конфигурацию где-нибудь править?

Comment: Не правильно поняли

Comment: @eri объясните, пожалуйста, как правильно?

Comment: в драйвере серсора ещё надо укзазать на каком CE он висит

Comment: @eri подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать? Это нужно править какой-то конфиг в Линукс?

Comment: шина spi это не плаг анд плей... как сенсор то прописывается в драйвера? через оверлей или через модпроб?

Comment: @eri не знаю, как это можно узнать?

Comment: @insolor если вешать на один spi, то как подсоединять провода? Никак не пойму, что с контактом P6 делать?

Comment: @Alexandr провода данных (MOSI, MISO) и тактовый (SCLK) - общие. Провода chip select (CE) отдельные для каждого устройства. Смотрите в этой статье "первый способ" (топология "звезда"): https://habr.com/ru/companies/first/articles/661511/. Что за P6 - не в курсе.